# Python's RSA.import-key to nodejs

Tags: python, node.js, rsa, cryptojs

```
RSA.import_key(b64encode(data))
```

It's Python code. I want to change this code to nodejs.
help me pls.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest reading the documentation for the [crypto module](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html) in NodeJS. Lots of methods directly accept private keys as Buffers, while there's also e.g. [crypto.createPrivateKey](https://nodejs.org/api/crypto.html#crypto_crypto_createprivatekey_key) you can use. Since security is an important topic, you're better off going through this module and carefully pick what suits your needs.